# RowFilter for JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I am trying to implement a RowFilter for my JTable but the issue is that my Table fetches data from a database and my table uses a JTextArea custom renderer for one column, I have implemented the RowFilter and it does work.

The problem is that when I search for data the table defaults back to normal view like how you would see it without the renderer, I want that when searching is done the table should retain its aesthetics. Please help. 
here is my code:

this is my renderer:

```
class wrap extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
        wrap() {
            super();
            setLineWrap(true);
            setEditable(false);
            setWrapStyleWord(true);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 10, 5, 10));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object value, boolean bln, boolean bln1, int i, int i1) {
            setText((String) value);
            setForeground(Tab.getForeground());
            setBackground(Tab.getBackground());
            setFont(Tab.getFont());
            return this;
        }
```

This is how i set my table:

```
public void ViewReports() {
        load l5 = new load();
        l5.setVisible(true);
        l5.j1.setText("Fetching Report.");
        SwingWorker worker1 = new SwingWorker() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                if (con == null) {
                    try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("Connection Details go here");

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tcom, "Connection error.");
                    }
                }
       try {
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select S_id as 'ID',c_name as 'Candidate Name',C_num as 'Number',Comments,call_status as 'Call Status', date_format(date1,'%d-%b-%y') as 'Date' from CallRecords order by S_id desc;");
                     rs5 = ps.executeQuery();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
             Tab.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
             Tab.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs5));
             Tab.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new wrap());
                    updateRowHeights(3, 300);

                    TableColumn c1 = Tab.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                    TableColumn c2 = Tab.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                    TableColumn c3 = Tab.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
                    TableColumn c4 = Tab.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
                    TableColumn c5 = Tab.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
                    TableColumn c6 = Tab.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);

                    c1.setPreferredWidth(50);
                    c2.setPreferredWidth(130);
                    c3.setPreferredWidth(120);
                    c4.setPreferredWidth(350);
                    c5.setPreferredWidth(100);
                    c6.setPreferredWidth(100);
                try {
                    rs5.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {}
                l5.dispose();
            }
        };
        worker1.execute();
}
```

and here is my Filter Method:

```
 private void filter(String filterText){
            TableModel dm =(TableModel) Tab.getModel();
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> tr=new TableRowSorter<>(dm);
            Tab.setRowSorter(tr);
            tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText));
        }

 private void RecordFilterKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
         String Text = RecordFilter.getText();
         filter(Text);
    }
```

I have also used DefaultTableModel instead of TableModel but to no avail. Any suggest will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tab.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs5));
```

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your names are correct, others are not. Be consistent and follow Java conventions!

Whenever you reset the model on a JTable the custom renderers and editors are reset.

So you need to add the custom renderer to the table AFTER setting the model.

Comment: So after `TableModel dm =(TableModel) Tab.getModel();` i should re run the part where i set my custom renderer ad editor. and thank you for the advice on variable names I will take care of that from now on. If there is anything else you would like to suggest I would really appreciate it.

Comment: No. I said you need to reset the renderers AFTER setting the model.  Changing the filter does not change the model. While it won't cause a problem, why would you reset the renderers every time you change the filter? That is not very efficient.

Comment: My dear friend would be at all possible if you could show me how. I really do thank you for your help. A small code snippet on how to reset the renderers would be immensely helpful. Consider me a noob.

Comment: There is no secret. Start with the code from the `TableFilterDemo` in the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). Just add the renderer when you add the model to the table. Once you get that code working then figure out why your real code isn't working. We are not here to debug your code. In fact we can't debug your code because we don't have accesses to your database. So all we can do it give you advice.